# Get $(this) in Conditional Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have js function

```
 $(" .prev.browse.left, .next.browse.right", spaceImageContainer).click(function () {
                    var naviIndex = '';
                    var currElem = '';
                    if ($('.navi a', spaceImageContainer).hasClass("active")) {
                        currElem = $(this); // need to get here .navi a with class active
                        naviIndex = $(this).index();
                    }
                   //...
                });
```

I need write to variable `currElem` object with class `active`. Currently i get object on what i click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about?

```
currElem = $('.navi a', spaceImageContainer);
if (currElem.hasClass("active")) {
    // do stuff here. for instence, hide it.
    currElem.hide('slow');
}
```

EDIT:

As @demo said:

```
$('.navi a', spaceImageContainer).each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        currElem = $(this);
        naviIndex = $(this).index();
    }
});
```

Comment: and if `$('.navi a', spaceImageContainer)` exists more than 1 time? 
Then i need use for example `each` and in `each` `$(this)` will work as i expect firstly?

Comment: something like this :    $('.navi a', spaceImageContainer).each(function() {
                            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                                currElem = $(this);
                                naviIndex = $(this).index();
                            }
                        });

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select just the *'.navi a'* element(s) that have a class of *'active'*, simply append *'active'* to the selector string as follows:

```
currElem = $('.navi a.active', spaceImageContainer);
```

This will select all *'a'* elements whose class is *'active'* and whose parent element has a class of *'navi'*. If those are the only elements you need, there's no reason to go through a loop and manually check yourself; that just slows your code down.

If, however, you really do want to select all the *'.navi a'* element(s) and then do something for *all* of them, but do something *special* for the one(s) that have a class of *'active'*, then you could do the following

```
$('.navi a', spaceImageContainer).each(function(){
    currElement = $(this);
    if (currElement.hasClass('active')){
        //do something special
    }
    else{
        //do something regular
    }
})
```

Note that in the callback function you specify for the *each* method, the *this* variable is the current '.navi a' element in the loop, instead of the element that you clicked.